# SSHing into another one of my machines, making some changes and pushing back - author is "root"?

Tags: git, github

Whenever I commit through the SSH, it has the author of the commit as "root". How do I change it to my actual Github username so it links to that account?

It's an Ubuntu machine if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `.gitconfig` file with these fields in the root of the repository:

```
[user]
    email = john.doe@mail.com
    name = John Doe
```

Comment: Other answer is better, your solution works at the repo level (which isn't a good thing for setting user name), while cjc343's answer works at the system's user level.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git) covers setting your email in your git configuration. Note that GitHub links commits based on the email(s) connected to your account.

In short: `git config --global user.email "me@here.com"`

The configuration node for your name is `user.name`.

Comment: You can also omit the --global flag if you only want to modify those settings for a particular repository.

Comment: I think it just ends up coming down to personal preference -- I like `--global` because you set it once and it applies to any repository as the current user (unless overridden for a particular repo). `--system` I wouldn't typically recommend, but it can be useful if you are the only user of several accounts on a machine.